# Find longest vector by summing some vectors in given set

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms

Given $n$ vector $(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2),(x_3, y_3),\dots,(x_n,y_n)$. Find a subset S of vector such that $\text{}\left |\sum_{v\in S} v\right |$

Sorry for my English.

Please give me a hint how to solve this problem.

Could this problem be solved if we replace 2-D vector with m-Dimisional vector ?

Comment: I think you are missing part of the problem... What is the subset supposed to do?

Comment: The title gives a hint...

Comment: @StephenBly, the problem asked for choose some vectors such that sum of them "create" new vector which has maximum length.

Comment: It is a finite problem; just look at each of the $2^n-1$ non-empty subsets, find its sum and then its length, compare them to pick out the biggest. But perhaps you want something more efficient.

Comment: Any thoughts on the answer I posted?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Sorry for my late upvote :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw a line through the origin, add up the vectors on one side of it, find the length of the sum. Then rotate that line. Every time it hits one of the vectors, do the calculation over again for the new set of vectors on one side of the rotated line. Once you have rotated the line all the way around, you will have done $n$ length calculations. Pick out the greatest length from those $n$ numbers.